# Dont' return generic type if is undefined

Tags: typescript, generic-type-argument

I dont know if is possible implement this with TS.

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=42&pln=8&pc=43#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBDArgG2AFXBAzlAvFAOQDmATgPbJgCMRUAPseVWAExEBQnAlgHbAIZJAGNoAcUrUAPADkAfFADenKFFCQAXLAQp0WSHiazVUVIgBGEVNpzAy-EpwC+3eMj4jgPCnyhkIEh47IUlWPGkMeQAKFmptMJkogEplV04AegyoAHkAayg42ihgkr84JDRMbBxOAKCQskSwHGiVNXMrG2JmqDoAGlMNCG1SKVouZ2TuLNyAaULxgGYoRAATNYg19QodSv0ausDgwSbxnGkx1iWiGPazS2tR3pvBtWHRopuXaczsnIWRQALCU8HwKMAylADLgjg1Ts0LldqDc7qZOk8euMoECiG91NhPuNcT8ZtlgaCoODIfxoTV+lALMhIeCoEJKGQ4SdQuc2ujHt0iL1cfiPsxifRZgAJCgAdygAFtEHloBgAMr+CDAZBkPyIPzsihkKAACyEEAA-KSgA) is a playground, could be better to understand.

---

I have a default type groups

```
type DefaultTypes = 'group1' | 'group2'
```

And a interface Group

```
interface Group<N> {
  type: DefaultTypes | N
  label: string
}
```

And a function to registerGroups

```
function registerGroups <T>(group: Group<T>) {}
```

This way I can add more type groups to DefaultTypes, but if I call `registerGroups({})` without generic type, TS don't return an error to a different group type.

Is there a way to make it works?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript infers type parameters from the arguments you passed in. In this case if you don't specify a type parameter the compiler will infer it based on the value you assign to `type`, so for this example:

```
registerGroups({
  label: 'Group 4',
  type: 'group4' // How make TS return an error here?
})
```

`T` is inferred as `group4`. This is the designed behavior and it is the way it should work. The best kind of generic function is the kind that does not require you to pass in the type parameters explicitly.

There is no build-in way to disable inference, there are some workarounds through, based on the idea we can confuse the compiler into giving up on inference at a certain argument site by using some conditional types. [This is solution](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546) from jcalz is the one I usually use in such cases. Pair this with a default for `T` of `never` and you get the expected behavior. The default is needed because if TS has no place to infer `T` from it defaults to `unknown`, and `unknown | N` is `unknown` so anything is assignable. But if `T` defaults to `never` we get `never | N` which simplifies to `N` so only values of type `N` will be assignable`:

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
function registerGroups <T = never>(group: Group<NoInfer<T>>) {}

// group4 is not in Types, but no error
registerGroups({
  label: 'Group 4',
  type: 'group4' // How make TS return an error here?
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBDArgG2AFXBAzlAvFAOQDmATgPbJgCMRUAPseVWAExEBQnAlgHbAIZJAGNoAcUrUAPADkAfFADenKFFCQAXLAQp0WSHiazVUVIgBGEVNpzAy-EpwC+3DdFkUAkn3hDpGIqEANoYALqhUBAAHoJ8ACZ4iHwgUAD8UAAMUNp8EABuQmEA3JzwyHwiwDwUfFBkECQ8dkKSrHgBBFB5hWTyABQs1NptMp4+fmQB8vIAlMqunAD0S1BDYAAsUM3dFMDbdQa4ADRQFsj7fBRRZJRknA1NLWSjYDj9KmrmVjbEr1AbIjHUzubSkKSbegrKAACQoAHcoABbRAAa2gGAAyvUIMBkGQ6skbncoAALIQQNIuWacIA)

Comment: Hi, Titian. Nice explanation. Where can I find this kind of master concepts? Is there a course or any kind of material "beyond the basics" that you can share? Thanks.

Comment: @DiogoLessa I'm sorry to disappoint, but I don't have any such material. Most of my knowledge comes from experimentation (either in projects or answering the stranger questions here) and form reading GH PRs for new features as they appear (these are especially instructive)

Comment: That is fine. I understand these aspects. Thanks awyway, I've already learned.